# Entity framework database first - Table per hierarchy (TPH) recursive relationship implementation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to implement TPH recursive relationship on one of the concrete types using Entity Framework 5 and Database first approach.
I have conceptual model, and table structure like this:

[image: Conceptual model]
[image: Table structure]

Also, i have recursive relationship like this in my database table.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseType]  
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BaseType_DerivedType] 
FOREIGN KEY([Derived1RecursiveId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BaseType] ([Id])
```

When i update model with this relation i get diagram like this:
[image: Problem - Model]

My question is:

How can i implement a recursive relationship in a database so that when model is updated from database (refreshed), recursive relationship is set on DerivedType1?

Comment: Is it correct that you are setting your recursive foreign key on the BASE object, but yet you want entity framework to only use it on the DERIVED type?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, i want to use it on derived type - marked with blue circle on image. The current situation is marked by a red rectangle. I explained in the question above - text and images. To simplify, i want that my 3rd picture looks like 1st(conceptual model) after model is updated from database.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for the EF model to automatically deduce that the Derived1RecourseiveId is part of the Derived1 class. But you can move the association in your edmx file manually. Just move the foreign key column, delete the association on your base table and recreate it on the derived. Once moved it will stay in your derived type even if you do a model refresh.